Как убрать использование разрешения QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, если в манифесте оно ужё отключено?
Play console ругается, что в моем приложении используется разрешение QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES.  На форумах пишут, что отключить его можно из манифеста, но проблема в том, что в манифесте у меня не прописано такое разрешение.
Подскажите, где ещё оно может прятаться?

Какая-то из библиотек может подтягивать. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer

Огромное спасибо. Наша через apk analyzer и удалила разрешение!
